# AJAX call not firing after single button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

My AJAX call isn't firing after a single button click, but if I rapidly click the button three or four times, it works.

I have the validation in there and if that is triggered, it works like it should with one click.

My Code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.FIRST_BTN').off().click(function() {
    //var id = $(this).attr("id");
    //alert("id is: " + id);
    var first_name = $("#first_name_main").val();
    var last_name = $("#last_name_main").val();
    var tech_id = $("#tech_id_main").val();
    var phone = $("#phone_main").val();
    var email = $("#email_main").val();
    if (first_name == '') {
      refresh2();
    } else if (last_name == '') {
      refresh2();
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'student_signup.php?action=tech_id',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
          first_name: first_name,
          last_name: last_name,
          tech_id: tech_id,
          phone: phone,
          email: email
        },
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
          $('#details').html(data);
          $('#myModal').modal('show');
          //refresh();
        }
      });
    }
  });

});


function refresh() {
  window.location.href = "student_signup.php";
}

function refresh2() {
  window.location.href = "student_signup.php?action=invalid";
}
```

```html
<button class='btn btn-primary FIRST_BTN' type='button' name='FIRST_BTN' id='FIRST_BTN'>Submit</button>
```

Comment: and why `.off()`

Comment: Also, don't use `async: false,`.

Comment: .off() reset the function after it run so I doesn't preform twice. async: flase is something justed tried because of my issues. Which doesn't change the result. I have to click the button couple time real fast to get it to work. I think the ajax needs more time to complete all the php methods it run with the ajax.

Comment: @JoshPhelps `.off()` doesn't do that; it removes any previously registered handlers, but it will leave the `.click()` handler in place. It would only have any effect if your top function was called a second time, but `.ready()` only fires once.

Comment: try removing document.ready

Comment: Your code is good as far as the `click` event triggering. My guess is that there is a problem with the server that you're posting the request to, or some kind of connection issue.

Comment: I would suggest looking at the network tab of your browser's developer console and see if the AJAX request shows up when you click your button. That will show you whether it's actually firing or not.

Comment: If you are just trying to make sure the ajax doesn't get called twice, put an `if(inprocess) return; else inprocess = true;` at the beginning and then in the on complete of the ajax set it back to false.  This will work better than `.off`.